# How do I avoid Bootstrap tab's URL hash?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

body of the tabs i would like the active tab not to appear in the URL

```
<body>

<div class="container mt-3">
  <h2>Dynamic Tabs with jQuery</h2>
  <p>Click on the Tabs to display the active and previous tab.</p>
```

navigation tabs home tab is active by default

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

tab panes containing the tab contents to be displayed

```
<div class="tab-content border mb-3">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="act"><b>Active Tab</b>: <span></span></p>
  <p class="prev"><b>Previous Tab</b>: <span></span></p>
</div>
```

javascript code to allow navigation between tabs

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
    $(this).tab('show');
  });
  $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(event){
    var x = $(event.target).text();         // active tab
    var y = $(event.relatedTarget).text();  // previous tab
    $(".act span").text(x);
    $(".prev span").text(y);
  });
});
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add  `event.preventDefault();` just after click function

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
     event.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
  });
  $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(event){
    var x = $(event.target).text();         // active tab
    var y = $(event.relatedTarget).text();  // previous tab
    $(".act span").text(x);
    $(".prev span").text(y);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>

<div class="container mt-3">
  <h2>Dynamic Tabs with jQuery</h2>
  <p>Click on the Tabs to display the active and previous tab.</p>  
  
navigation tabs home tab is active by default

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

<div class="tab-content border mb-3">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="act"><b>Active Tab</b>: <span></span></p>
  <p class="prev"><b>Previous Tab</b>: <span></span></p>
</div>
javascript code to allow navigation between tabs


</body>
```